# Any examples of implementing DotNetOpenId on ASP.NET State Server?

Tags: .net, dotnetopenauth, web-farm, stateserver

We have dotopenopenId implemented on our web farm which currently uses scaleout. We want to replace ScaleOut with ASP.NET State Server, but I'm wondering if there are any examples of the interfaces that need to be built for the AssociationStore and the ProviderStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best examples of state stores for DotNetOpenAuth are found in [the project templates](https://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth/download?package=DotNetOpenAuth+project+templates). These stores use a shared database so that all servers on the web farm share the state, as appropriate.